# Error when trying to build a dev container from VSCode

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to build a new dev container from the DevContainer extension it self through the path:

- Dev Containers: New Dev Container
- Configuration model: Ubuntu
- Additional Options:
- jammy (default)
- Python
- Default

Every single time I get an error like the following:

```
[146507 ms] Start: Run: docker run -d --mount type=volume,src=hands_on_ml,dst=/workspaces -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock vsc-volume-bootstrap sleep infinity
[146772 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[146966 ms] Start: Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /workspaces/hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --log-level debug --log-format json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[147191 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.20.1. linux 5.14.0-1048-oem x64.
[147191 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[147198 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml
[147220 ms] Start: Run in container: test -e "/home/tamiris" || (mkdir -p "$(dirname "/home/tamiris")" && ln -s ~ "/home/tamiris")
[147224 ms] 
[147224 ms] 
[147224 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/devcontainer-70914c47-d8bc-4410-a067-554a57036f4a.json' >/tmp/devcontainer-70914c47-d8bc-4410-a067-554a57036f4a.json_1691065022912
[147226 ms] 
[147226 ms] 
[147227 ms] Start: Run in container: docker volume ls -q
[147314 ms] Start: Run in container: docker volume create vscode
[147550 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml
[147630 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[147714 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml
[147794 ms] Start: Run in container: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml
[147974 ms] Start: Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /workspaces/hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-70914c47-d8bc-4410-a067-554a57036f4a.json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[148196 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.20.1. linux 5.14.0-1048-oem x64.
[148196 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[148204 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[148352 ms] Start: Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-46212c2d-8e6c-48e6-ad2f-777ae12972691691064875114 --workspace-folder /workspaces/hands_on_ml --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-70914c47-d8bc-4410-a067-554a57036f4a.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=hands_on_ml,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root true
[148620 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.20.1. linux 5.14.0-1048-oem x64.
[148620 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[148677 ms] github.com/docker/buildx v0.8.2 6224def4dd2c3d347eee19db595348c50d7cb491
[148677 ms] 
[148677 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[148681 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[148835 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --filter label=vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[148854 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy
[151011 ms] local container features stored at: /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/node_modules/vscode-dev-containers/container-features
[151014 ms] Start: Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[151040 ms] Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1'...
[151040 ms] * Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1
[151278 ms] Start: Run: docker-credential-secret get
[152301 ms] Error getting blob: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com
[152303 ms] Error: Failed to download package for ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python
[152303 ms]     at fg (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1830:18444)
[152304 ms]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[152304 ms]     at async dN (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1830:25657)
[152304 ms]     at async Uee (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1830:24252)
[152304 ms]     at async Mf (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1830:26406)
[152304 ms]     at async mg (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1830:26630)
[152305 ms]     at async xg (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1935:2367)
[152305 ms]     at async Gf (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1937:1830)
[152305 ms]     at async _g (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1937:280)
[152305 ms]     at async fC (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2007:1729)
[152316 ms] Exit code 1
[152316 ms] Start: Run: docker rm -f 24ffd9678fc818b6a00ffbaf8cf1e8bbb00e3f17403f4938c2437577babed5f2
[152323 ms] Command failed: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-46212c2d-8e6c-48e6-ad2f-777ae12972691691064875114 --workspace-folder /workspaces/hands_on_ml --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.name=hands_on_ml --id-label vsc.devcontainer.volume.folder=hands_on_ml --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/hands_on_ml/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-70914c47-d8bc-4410-a067-554a57036f4a.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=hands_on_ml,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root true
[152323 ms] Exit code 1
[320145 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[320162 ms] 1.43
[320163 ms] Start: Run: docker pull alpine:3.16.3
[320867 ms] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
```

I already:

- Uninstall and reinstall the extension Dev Containers
- Verify the Docker version and Docker Compose version
- Performed `docker system prune -a` (all images, containers, and volumes were removed)
- Performed `sudo apt upgrade & apt update & apt autoremove`
- Restarted the computer

I also tried other built-in configurations from Dev Containers.
My system is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Does someone know what else I can do?

Comment: The error you're encountering seems to be related to the inability of your Dev Container to download a required Docker image from GitHub Container Registry (ghcr.io). The specific error message "Error getting blob: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com" indicates a network issue preventing your Docker daemon from reaching the GitHub Container Registry server.

Comment: I thought that, but I don't know how to fix this. Any clue?

Comment: It was just my VPN...